# Using NuGetPowerTools with a local feed

Tags: nuget

I'm trying to implement the no commit workflow as outlined here
http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages

However I have some custom packages set up in a local feed (on a network drive) and get the following error when I try to pull down the source from our repository
C:\myproj.nuget\NuGet.targets(6,9): error : Unable to find version '1.0' of package MyPackage

Is there a way to automatically point at the local feed when the powertools do their magic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NuGetPowerTools uses a NuGet.settings.targets file in the .nuget folder to pass parameters to nuget.exe's restore command. You can add that source to list of packages sources in VS (which go into %AppData%\NuGet\NuGet.config) and have it get picked up automatically or you can specify the  property during build with the list of packages sources you want to use to restore.